# How to add a relation if parent deleted then child should automatically delete in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key, relationship

I have two tables names as

**1.**`tbl_testquestion` (qu_id primary)

```
+-------+----------+--------+
| qu_id | question | status |
+-------+----------+--------+
| 1     | who      | 1      |
+-------+----------+--------+
| 2     | why      | 1      |
+-------+----------+--------+
| 3     | what     | 1      |
+-------+----------+--------+
```

**2.**`tbl_testanswer` (id_answer primary)

(*qu_id is from tbl_testquestion which is primary in that table*)

```
+-----------+-------+--------+----------------+--------+
| id_answer | qu_id | answer | correct_answer | status |
+-----------+-------+--------+----------------+--------+
| 1         | 1     | me     | 1              | 1      |
+-----------+-------+--------+----------------+--------+
| 2         | 1     | you    | 0              | 1      |
+-----------+-------+--------+----------------+--------+
| 3         | 1     | they   | 0              | 1      |
+-----------+-------+--------+----------------+--------+
| 4         | 1     | us     | 0              | 1      |
+-----------+-------+--------+----------------+--------+
| 5         | 2     | mark   | 0              | 1      |
+-----------+-------+--------+----------------+--------+
| 6         | 2     | chen   | 0              | 1      |
+-----------+-------+--------+----------------+--------+
| 7         | 2     | ben    | 1              | 1      |
+-----------+-------+--------+----------------+--------+
| 8         | 2     | kun    | 0              | 1      |
+-----------+-------+--------+----------------+--------+
```

So when i try to delete any record from table `tbl_testquestion` then all records should be get deleted i.e all records with same *qu_id* from *tbl_testanswer*

SO how can i add foreign key or some other ..?

Comment: Check this one  http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Comment: how to write alter for FOREIGN KEY DELETE CASCADE @SagarGangwal